# sql select and delete from same table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run this sql query to clean up old data

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta 
where wp_postmeta.post_id=(
 SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta pm 
 WHERE (meta_key like '_form_id') AND 
 pm.post_id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts))
```

Getting the error

> "Table 'wp_postmeta' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data"

What is the correct SQL?

Thanks.

Comment: could you try with in instead of = (eqaul)

Comment: Unless you're using a case sensitive collation , 'like' isn't useful here

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're overcomplicating the problem, you don't need the subquery here. Also my guess is that you're missing the percent sign in `LIKE`.

```
 DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '%_form_id'
    AND post_id NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts);
```

Comment: That looks kind of like a subquery